# .net core 2 angular 5 prerender failed

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm getting the following error:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

I have followed the following documentation from microsoft themselves:
https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio

So the prerendering gets triggered but it fails because on the server side window does not exist ofcourse.

Now i have seen fixes for the older angular template from Visual Studio which came with Angular 4. The one from the documentation has Angular 5 and is build up a little different. So I have found fixes but they do not work because I do not have an index.cshtml. In the new template you get a normal index.html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test/title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/93acba991a.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The solution for the first project was :

> replace the "asp-prerender-module" with "asp-ng2-prerender-module"

As you can see i do not have a asp-prerender-module in there, and changing it to "asp-ng2-prerender-module" does not work for me. I'm using the @agm/core package which gives me this error, but i heard multiple packages suffer from this problem. I hope anyone has a fix for this issue.